# Jede Menge is used to modify plural noun or singular noun?

Tags: adjective

In this sentence —- Hier gibt es jede Menge interessante Gebäude.

Es gibt should always be followed by Akkusativ, if I’m not wrong.

I thought Jede Menge is used to modify the pl. noun Gebäude, if so, interessant should be interessantEN instead of interessantE as Jede in the front.

But my text book shows this as interessantE which would take Gebäude as a singular Nt. (das Gebäude) with Jede in the front, the adjective declension of interessant should be interessantE.

So, may I seek any of your help to explain if the interessantE used here is correct? or jede Menge is usually to modify pl. n. or singular noun?

Many thanks in advance,
Canny

Answer (score 1):

"Jede Menge" is a **Sammelbezeichnung** (a phrase to express a collection) and it is colloquial.

The rules from "jeder" as in

> *Jeder* **zweite** Mensch.   (weak)
> *Ein jeder* **zweiter/zweite** Mensch ist gut.   (weak or strong)
> *Einem jedem* **zweiten** Menschen geht es gut.  (weak when "jeder" is inflected)

... do not apply.

You need to see it like this:

> Hier gibt es [jede Menge [interessante Gebäude]]

"Jede Menge" is in apposition to "interessante Gebäude". I.e. it does not influence it.

The "core" of *jede Menge interessante Gebäude* is **Menge**, not **Gebäude**.
You have to memorize that in *appositions* like yours, the left part is the core, and the right part ("interessante Gebäude") is the secondary core that is appended.

This has consequences for the verb, when you use such a phrase as the subject of your sentence, but it also gives you the freedom to choose the number of your verb by meaning instead of by grammar rules. But this is another topic.

Comment: Hi Oran, Thanks for your explanation. My first time to look at this structure this way as you explained.

Comment: Hi Oran, by your explanation to look at this separately, Menge and Gebäude, with jede and interessantE in the front respectively makes sense to me. Thanks again for your prompt help!